# gtkmm - drawing primitives (and text) on window with keeping an old content

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gdk

I want to draw some primitives (for example lines or text) on given window with gtkmm (gdkmm / gdk) with keeping old content of this window. I guess that using `DrawingArea` widget may be no helpful because I need draw on the old `pixbuf`.
Maybe I need to rearrange this `pixbuf` and load it again to this window? Is it possible?
Maybe I need to instert something between `begin_paint_region()` and `end_paint()`?

thanks.

Comment: Why not use cairo? It's really easy to do what you want.

Comment: Is the widget that currently shows the pixbuf under your control?

Comment: I'm very beginner in cairo @LiuLang, what should I do exactly?

Comment: @kelsar, here is a simple tutorial about cairo.  http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/